# Problem with setting Project Facets

Tags: web-services, jax-rs

As said in the following IBM tutorial, http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/xml/x-springandroid/x-springandroid-pdf.pdf I have tried to create a JAX RS web services.

But I am not able to set the Project facets to JAX - RS as I don't get any such options. Also, I wanted to know hoew do i set the class path of server to the respective jars.

I am using Eclipse Ganymade IDE

Thanks
Sneha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have to use Helios version of eclipse to get those options for JAX RS. I was using ganymade version. Also,To set the class path i just nedd to copy the jars to lib folder.